# R/SparkR on Apache Zeppelin: how to set the plot size?

Tags: r, plot, size, apache-zeppelin, sparkr

I run a *SparkR* notebook within *Apache Zeppelin* successfully. However, when I create plots (standard R plots, not ggplot), I wanna control the **size** of the figure, i.e. **width** and **height**. Any idea?

Btw, I use **livy**, so my snippets look like:

```
%livy2.sparkr
x = rnorm(10)
plot(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to change the width of your paragraph

Comment: Changing paragraph does not work. The width of the plot does not go above a certain (restricted) bound.

Comment: The width of the *paragraphs* can be adjusted from 1 to 12. From 1 to 4 the *plot width* adjusts, but if I enter 5-12, the plot width does not widen anymore.

@zjffdu - can you confirm you are able to enlarge the plot to the full (=12) width with the latest Zeppelin? If yes, I have to check my branch. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I can change it from 1 to 12

Comment: Pity the 2.6.3 version (latest on Hortonworks) actually does not seem to support this (says our DevOps): changing width to 12 will not widen the plot to 12. However thanks for your input, @zjffdu.

Comment: For help on how to change the paragraph widths in a Zeppelin notebook, see the "paragraph" section here: https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.6.1/quickstart/explorezeppelinui.html

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately livy.sparkr, use to render every plot in a png image as shown [here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-livy/blob/c1aafeb6cb87f2bd7f4cb7cf538822b59fb34a9c/repl/src/main/scala/org/apache/livy/repl/SparkRInterpreter.scala#L199) and report [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LIVY-433), you can however increase your plot image by saving the image and display it as an img html tag  as show on this [post](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/How-to-enable-graphics-in-R-interpreter/ta-p/249423).

to do the trick :

```
set.seed(42)
# create your plot and save it into a png
png("/tmp/myplot.png")
plot(rnorm(10))
dev.off()              # Close device

# get base64 of the image for display in html
printImageURI<-function(file,width=1000,height=1000){
    uri=image_uri(file)
    file.remove(file)
    cat(sprintf("%%html <img width='%ipx' height='%ipx' src=\"%s\" />\n",width,height,uri))
}
printImageURI("/tmp/myplot.png",700,800)
```